# Excel, change measure in survey data

Tags: excel, excel-pivot

nice to meet you.

i'd like to get your help for changing the variable to the original one in fast way.
** if you aren't able to find the way. then, do i have to change them one at a time?

here is what i want to get.

and i'll attach the sample data.

thank you
best regards,
kyle.

find the way but, i was not able to find the correct way.
i'd like you guys to find and study the way along with me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gCbL.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.